# Even with copy.deepcopy(django.model), _meta options are shared

Tags: django, attributes

I have several tables with exactly the same structure (columns) but different elements (rows). These tables are spatial grids and each table defines a zooming level, therefore it's not necessary to write a model for each one (at least that's what I thought). My approach was to change the attribute ._meta.db_table to the table I need to do my stuff.

The problem is that if I instantiate an object M, say for level 1 (i.e. M._meta.db_table == "table-level-1"), and then instantiate another object N, say for level 2 (i.e. N._meta.db_table == "table-level-2") that same attribute in object M will change as well. Even if I use a deep copy of it!

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you've done, but here's how I would implement multiple models with the same structure.

```
class MyBase(models.Model):
    foo = models.Integer()
    # and so on
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MySubOne(MyBase):
    pass

class MySubTwo(MyBase):
    pass
```

By setting abstract=True on the base model, Django won't create a table for that model. But it will create a table for each of the models that inherits from it. More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: I didn't know that specification. Thank you very much!